# Sql Server if - end if with select

Tags: sql-server

How can i write WHERE clause using IF - END IF. I using stored procedure. I have 3 parameter. If all parameter have value then it is ok and i don't have problem. But if one parameter is empty i want to use WHERE CLAUSE without that parameter whic is empty. See my example:

```
 @Godina int,
 @Korisnik int,
 @Nalog int

select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PROMTRAN] ORDER BY [PROMDATU]) AS [R],
    P.PROMGODI,
    P.PROMKORI,
    P.PROMBROJ,
    P.PROMTRAN,
    P.PROMDATU,
    o.OPIS AS OPIS,
    P.PROMUPLA,
    P.PROMISPLA


    from tPROM P
    left outer join tNALO N
    on p.PROMGODI = N.NALOGODI and p.PROMKORI = n.NALOKORI and p.PROMBROJ =          n.NALOBROJ
    left outer join tOpis O
    on p.PROMOPIS = O.PROMOPIS
 )
        Select  [PROMKORI], [PROMBROJ],R AS [RB],[PROMTRAN],[PROMDATU],  [OPIS],  [PROMUPLA],[PROMISPLA]
    From OrderCTE
    Where Godina = '14' and Kori = '1' and Nalog = @Nalog

 --********************************
 IF @Nalog NULL OR '' THEN
 Where Godina = '14' and Kori = '1'
    ELSE

Where Godina = '14' and Kori = '1' and Nalog = @Nalog
END IF
--*******************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it with `OR`:

```
WHERE Godina = '14' AND Kori = '1' AND (Nalog = @Nalog OR @Nalog IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dynamic SQL, however this can be done like that:

```
WHERE Godina = '14'
    AND Kori = '1'
    AND (Nalog = @Nalog OR NULLIF(@Nalog, '') IS NULL)
```